# Странное поведение strings.Replace() в go

Tags: golang

Есть код:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Replace(" ноль ноль ноль ", " ноль ", " 0 ", -1))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/AYIZp_DD28B

Почему в выводе будет:

```
 0 ноль 0
```

а не

```
 0 0 0
```

Объсните, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Читайте [документацию](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/strings/#ReplaceAll) внимательно:

> ReplaceAll returns a copy of the string s with all *non-overlapping* instances of old replaced by new. If old is empty, it matches at the beginning of the string and after each UTF-8 sequence, yielding up to k+1 replacements for a k-rune string.

(Выделение добавлено.)

В вашем же случае явно есть перекрытие.